# Ionic - Error "no native targets found" showing up when trying to run on the device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, adb, capacitor

I have managed to connect to the device via ADB both with TCP and USB mode. But Ionic seems failed to detect the device. NPM version is 8.3.1 and Capacitor version is 3.3.4. Both @capacitor/core and @capacitor/cli was installed. I had looking for the solution in other Ionic's community sites and none of them is helping.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didn't set the Android SDK path for ANDROID_HOME either globally or locally. I'm also working on Flutter but having encounter no such problem on it.